# How to link Facebook App User Id with Messenger Id for use with Facebook Messenger Bot

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I have a Facebook app that users log in to with a mobile app, using a Facebook login button. That user ID, which is app-specific, is how we identify that user.

Is there a way to determine that app-specific user ID from messenger through a Facebook bot? I don't think there is, but if someone can think of a workaround, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround and wrote about it some time ago.
(Its very hacky )

FB Messenger Bot  — How to identify a user via page- & app-scoped user-id’s
https://chatbotsmagazine.com/fb-messenger-bot-how-to-identify-a-user-via-page-app-scoped-user-ids-f95b807b7e46#.5ak8mikm4

Let me know if you need more help!

Comment: I considered that for a moment but I figured since that URL expires and people can change their profile picture, that it wasn't a great solution. Thankfully they added account linking recently

Comment: i think this is possible now with id matching api: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/connecting-accounts

Comment: yes it is! the new id matching api is the way to go.